# Applications that reside in memory both running and cached

Tags: applications, ram

I can see some apps running in background even if I have blocked that app's background data. I don't need to force close that app from developer options.

I need to know,

1. what is the duration of keeping an app (which is not opened) in ram. (It may be a system app, and I know that system app is required for better functioning. For example Bluetooth, I have turned on and turned off, but it showed in running services)
2. What is the duration of an app (which is opened recently) kept in ram. Opened app is closed also removed from overview (recents).
3. Why are some apps loaded to ram automatically? (Into Cached processes)

Running 8.0 Oreo in moto x4

Comment: AFAIK the duration is simple: Until a different app needs the RAM.